# IOS xcode 8 have 2 library appear in red

Tags: ios, frameworks

Hi I have an IOS project which has 2 library missing (appear in red, can not show in Finder) the project still build successfull but when I delete 2 libs, The build will stop.

Any what is this 2 libs any can we safety delete them?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Don't worry, From iOS 9 `.dylib` extention changed to `.tbd`. Just search again the same files in **Linked Frameworks and Libraries** section and add those files with `.tbd` extension.

You don't need to remove those `.dylib` files because its supporting prior version of iOS 9.

Comment: Thanks a lots. Do you know that is these 2 libs do? should we delete and add .tbd?

Comment: You can keep it if you want to support prior version of iOS 9 i.e, iOS 8. If your app deployment target is iOS 9 or higher then you should remove it.

Comment: Thanks the app is for ipad and target ios 9 so i delete and add .tbd file. But still wanna know which function these 2 libs do (what frame work or function  libstdc and libiconv do?)

Comment: Will dig into in to get more info. Btw. I have 1 more problem with xcode. can help me take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40652331/ios-xcode-8-dsymulti-warning