# IOS Xcode 8 Dsymulti Warning

Tags: ios, xcode, dsym

I just update my project to Xcode 8 but don't know why my xcode console is flood with Dsymulti warning message.

```
while processing /Volumes/Data/OneDrive/Singpost/Esam/Vic/Version1/SAM/eSAM/SAMKiosk/Classes/Libs/NETS/libNETS.a(NETS.o):
warning: /Users/Chetas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/9CPWN0R8YQPE/Foundation-A3SOD99KJ0S9.pcm: No such file or directory
note: Linking a static library that was built with -gmodules, but the module cache was not found.  Redistributable static libraries should never be built with module debugging enabled.  The debug experience will be degraded due to incomplete debug information.
while processing /Volumes/Data/OneDrive/Singpost/Esam/Vic/Version1/SAM/eSAM/SAMKiosk/Classes/Libs/NETS/libNETS.a(NETS.o):
warning: /Users/Chetas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/9CPWN0R8YQPE/ObjectiveC-2CD0WTQVXITO7.pcm: No such file or directory
while processing /Volumes/Data/OneDrive/Singpost/Esam/Vic/Version1/SAM/eSAM/SAMKiosk/Classes/Libs/NETS/libNETS.a(NETS.o):
warning: /Users/Chetas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/9CPWN0R8YQPE/CoreFoundation-10I2D2XL7L7X9.pcm: No such file or directory
```

My project still can build successfully. Any one know how can we deal with these warnings?

Comment: First quit XCode and Simulator. Then clear DerivedData. Open Xcode, clean the project and run again.

Comment: Hi seem not working. I follow the sequence but still have these warning. The address /Users/Chetas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/9CPWN0R8... is belong to our colleague project computer

Comment: Maybe some files are not found.

Comment: But I can still can build and run the project . Just he warning . may be we need to clear some thing

Answer (score 0):

For me, I could solve setting in `Build Settings`

```
Generate Debug Symbols = No
```